# cleanest partial application of subtraction operator

Tags: ocaml, subtraction, partial-application

If I want a function that subtracts an `int` argument from the number 2, I can do

```
let two_minus = (-) 2
```

But what if I want a function that subtracts 2 **from** an int argument?

In Haskell, I can do

```
let minus2 = flip (-) 2
```

But in Ocaml 4.02, `flip` is not part of the standard library.

For now, I've settled on

```
let minus2 = (+) ~-2
```

which adds negative 2 to an `int` argument. I find it looks cleaner than

```
let minus2 = fun x -> x-2
```

... or at least it takes less characters.

Is there a better, more idiomatic way?

Comment: `let minus2 x = x - 2` is pretty short and succinct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Haskell, you can do what you want with operator sections, which is much cleaner than `flip` imo:

```
Prelude> :t (2 -)
(2 -) :: Num a => a -> a
Prelude> :t ((-) 2)
((-) 2) :: Num a => a -> a
```

OCaml does not support this nicety (afaik). However, if you like `flip`, it is trivial to define your own:

```
let flip f x y = f y x;;
```

Or you can use a standard library that has it defined already, like `Core` and `Batteries`. E.g.,

```
# open Core 
utop # Fn.flip;;
- : ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'b -> 'a -> 'c = <fun>
```

fwiw, in the absence of operator sections, I find `fun x -> x-2`  much clearer than either of the two alternatives you propose. It may not look as nice, but it is immediately clear what it means.

Favoring clear and *very* explicit expressions over clever and concise ones is very idiomatic OCaml.

Answer (score 1):

OCaml is a programming language.  You are free to define whatever you feel convenient:

```
let flip f x y = f y x
```